# HTML table with auto-fit for some columns, fixed width for others

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to create a table adhering to the following requirements:

1. The table width must be defined as 0 - the browser should calculate the width according to the column widths (this is to accommodate a column-resize plugin).
2. Some columns may receive a fixed width (e.g. 50px);
3. Columns that do not receive a fixed width, must auto-fit to the content.

I have created a [small example](http://jsfiddle.net/sangil/HbARP/) to illustrate the problem - as you can see column 3 stays at width 0 and so is not visible.

***EDIT***: If "table-layout: fixed" is removed. the third column appears, but the fixed widths are ignored and all columns become auto-fit.

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="cell header" id="header1">Header 1</td>
    <td class="cell header" id="header2">Header 2</td>
    <td class="cell header" id="header3">Header 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="cell">Cell 1</td>
    <td class="cell">Cell 2</td>
    <td class="cell">Very looooong content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #696969;
}

.cell {
    color: #898989;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    padding: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
    background-color: lightsteelblue;
    color: black;
}

#header1, #header2 {
    width: 50px;
}
```

Is this even possible? Any help would be appreciated...

​

Comment: Is there a reason why removing `width: 0;` or swapping it with `width: auto;` wouldn't work with your column resize plugin? Those changes do exactly what you need in the demo, but I'm not sure about the plugin. http://jsfiddle.net/HbARP/43/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible with table-layout: fixed and a width of 0 on your table.

Form the [W3 Spec section 17.5.2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#propdef-table-layout):

> In the fixed table layout algorithm, the width of each column is
>   determined as follows:
>
> 1. A column element with a value other than 'auto' for the 'width' property sets the width for that column.
> 2. Otherwise, a cell in the first row with a value other than 'auto' for the 'width' property determines the width for that column. If the
>      cell spans more than one column, the width is divided over the
>      columns.
> 3. Any remaining columns equally divide the remaining horizontal table space (minus borders or cell spacing).

However, when you do the automatic layout (described in section 17.5.2.2) your widths will be pushed around to work with your content and only use the widths provided when possible. For instance, if the sum of the minimum widths of each column exceeds the container width of your table, everything will get shifted around to fit independent of what widths you set.

It should be also noted that:

> UAs are not required to implement this algorithm to determine the table layout in the case that 'table-layout' is 'auto'; they can use any other algorithm even if it results in different behavior.

So it looks like the answer is a unfortunately a long-winded "no" :(