# convert fixed tables to responsive for mobile

Tags: css, mobile, responsive

the URL is http://action.news 
there are 3 columns in a fixed width table)

(i removed the script that loads on demand) to make things easier. 
thank you kindly

what i have done:
added this code below

https://gist.github.com/hkirsman/3002480

added this per google instructions

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

i have read [HTML table with auto-fit for some columns, fixed width for others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671488/html-table-with-auto-fit-for-some-columns-fixed-width-for-others)

but still cant get the page to be mobile friendly, the top part seems to realign

Comment: Is it possible you can use divs or a list instead of a table to display content? Tables are quite tricky to make responsive

Answer (score 1):

I've found this example on the Codepen so you can try it and adjust it to your needs:

Here's some code

HTML:

```
<table class="js-table participants-table">
  <caption>
    <p>Responsive Table</p>
  </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Picture</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!--filled from javascript-->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
HTML {
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

BODY {
  margin: 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

IMG {
  max-width: 100%;
}


/*Style For Table*/

.participants-table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}

.participants-table TD,
.participants-table TH {
  border: 1px solid #b4adad;
}

.participants-table IMG {
  width: 150px;
}

.participants-table THEAD {
  display: none;
}

.participants-table TD {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 450px) {
  .participants-table {
    width: auto;
  }
  .participants-table TD,
  .participants-table TH {
    padding: .2em 1em;
  }
  .participants-table THEAD {
    display: table-header-group;
  }
  .participants-table TD {
    display: table-cell;
    position: static;
  }
  .participants-table TD:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

[link to the example](https://codepen.io/Konrud/pen/QGEdwZ)